# Previous screen flashing when restarting the app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Short description of the problem: First time when the app is opened the splash screen appears normally and than it is followed by the home screen. But after the app was closed from taskmanager (double click on home button and swipe up) and opened again, the previous(cached) home screen appears(flashing) for a very short time before the Splash screen appears. I think every iOS app running on iOS 11.4 (ios 9 and 10 not affected) is affected not just mine. As you can see below(slow motion video), I could reproduce it with the Twitter app also - firstly it opens normally and at the second time the problem appears.

[image: ios previous screen flashing before splash screen at startup]

My application is suffering constantly from this issue in a predictable way, but the Twitter and other apps are not. They produce this symptom every now and again but than nothing for the following 5-10 try. With normal usage - if I don't terminate the app manually or there are a few app opened between mine is closed and reopened - the problem is not appearing.
The question is, is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Are you looking for a workaround for your app or for every app?

Comment: I think this is a bug in iOS, but if there is a workaround at the moment, I will be satisfied with it.

Comment: Again a workaround for just your app or all apps on your phone?

Comment: I am a developer, I don't really care about other apps, I just used them to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623097-ignoresnapshotonnextapplicationl

Comment: As @DonMag has said or your app that should be the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App screen snapshot being shown instead of launchScreen during state restoration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571418/app-screen-snapshot-being-shown-instead-of-launchscreen-during-state-restoration)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line of code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
UIApplication.shared.ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch()
```