# ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch() not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to "prevent the app from using the recent snapshot image during the next launch cycle" using the ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch() method documented at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623097-ignoresnapshotonnextapplicationl

Apple very specifically says "You must call this method from within the code you use to preserve your app’s state."

I am calling this method from every single possible Saving and Restoration method without success. Including encodeRestorableStateWithCoder() as mentioned in [App screen snapshot being shown instead of launchScreen during state restoration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571418/app-screen-snapshot-being-shown-instead-of-launchscreen-during-state-restoration)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to call `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch` in every possible methods and it still seems broken to me.

Instead, I ended up using a fake launch image to prevent user from seeing the real App content:

```c
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  // This line doesn't seem to work...
  // [application ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch];

  self.appCover = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.window frame]];
  // setup a little in order to make our fake looks better
  self.appCover.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
  self.appCover.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  // This is the image we use in our LaunchScreen.xib
  [self.appCover setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage"]];
  [self.window addSubview:self.appCover];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  // get rid of the fake launch image after App become active
  if (self.appCover) {
    [self.appCover removeFromSuperview];
    self.appCover = nil;
  }
}
```

Not perfect but works like what `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch` should do.

---

**2019-04-11 UPDATE:**

This is pretty embarrassing: turns out my app crashes every time after `-[UIApplication terminateWithSuccess]` due to some third party frameworks not being released properly.

So in my case, I just need to release these frameworks correctly in `applicationWillTerminate`, and everything works as expected. (don't even need the `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch` approach)